# Email always ends up in spam

Tags: php, wp-mail

I created a function which I use to send an email when a specific button is pressed. This works great, except that it always ends up in spam instead of the inbox.

This is the function:

```
function search_notify_email() {
  // Set variables
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $content = $_POST['content'];
  $location = $_POST['location'];
  $siteurl = $_POST['siteurl'];
  $networkurl = network_site_url();
  $themeurl = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
  // Call Change Email to HTML function
  add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_email_html_content_type' );
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Attention: Test!";
    $message = "<html>
    <body>
      Testing
    </body>
    </html>";
    $headers[] = 'From: Example <noreply@example.com>';

    if ( wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ) {
      // Success
    } else {
      // Error
    }
    die();
    // Remove filter HTML content type
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_email_html_content_type' );
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_search_notify_email', 'search_notify_email');
add_action('wp_ajax_search_notify_email', 'search_notify_email');
```

I have other emails sent on my site with the same email address used and these do not end up in the spam folder.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

There are a wide variety of things this could be, so any answers to this question would be speculation. Keep in mind, it's the email that gets marked as spam (and the details of the sender, domain, etc), not the code that generates the email.

That being said, I would investigate the sender information first to make sure the headers in the email are set to show the email is sent via a valid email address with the a domain that matches the sender's domain or is authorized to send on behalf of the domain.

You can try a testing service like [MXToolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/deliverability) to ensure email is being delivered successfully.

Comment: Yes, I understand there could be many reasons. But the thing is that other plugins that use wp_mail works just fine, and isn't marked as spam. The email adress is existing (a real adress) on the same domain I have setup. Is there any specific headers that must be setup for wp_mail to work?

Comment: Just tested MXToolbox and all the following shows red crosses: DMARC Compliant (No DNS Found), SPF Alignment, SPF Authenticated, DKIM Alignment, DKIM Authenticated but the email was delivered and it is not blacklisted.

Comment: You're using `From: Example <noreply@example.com>` in your example. Is this what you have in your code? This should match your sender email.

Comment: The issue has to do with that I can see now. My mail is sent from `noreply@example.com` but when looking at the email source I can see that the sender is actually `example@server123.web-hosting.com` which means it doesn't match. But I cannot figure out how other plugins do this, and work fine with wp_mail, where I can use noreply@example.com and it will be used in both sender and from.

Comment: Since I cannot see your situation, I can't answer that question. I can tell you that `example.com` is reserved for testing, so many services might treat this domain differently.

Comment: Sorry, for not being clear. I don't actually use example.com, I replaced that here on stackexchange to hide my URL for the moment. In reality I use my proper URL, and proper server.web-hosting.com

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in the comments of another answer that the email address used is a real address.  However, you didn't mention whether `wp_mail()` is actually sending **through** that account (as opposed to **from** which is different).  It may seem confusing, but it's an important distinction.

If you haven't set up to send through that account via SMTP and you're just replacing the "from" address, **you are still sending through the web server's email server**.  There are parts of that process that make your email header look "spammy."

If you're not connecting `wp_mail()` to SMTP, I highly recommend that you do.  That will solve a number of possible spam issues.  If you can't or won't, there are still actions you can take.

When *not* connecting `wp_mail()` to an authenticated SMTP account, I would recommend that you set the "sender" to be the same value as the "from" address.  Otherwise, in the email header, if these are two different values, it raises a red flag for the spam filter.  Here's how to do it:

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'fix_my_email_return_path' );

function fix_my_email_return_path( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->Sender = $phpmailer->From;
}
```

There's [a more detailed overview of the approach in this article](https://www.butlerblog.com/2014/11/24/change-wordpress-email-settings-to-reduce-spam-rejection/).